# SugarCE: How to pass data (selected checkboxes) from popup window to main form?

Tags: checkbox, popup, sugarcrm

I have created a related field which allows user to choose multiple items. Now my problem is when user click `Select` button I don't know how to get data which chosen by user ( in this case, it's an array of selected checkboxes) so I can display them on main form.

I'm using SugarCE-6.5.13.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, Bind a on click js event on the select button

```
$('#search_form_select').click(function(){sendToParent();})
```

Second, When clicking the select button, find all checked rows and set value to parent window

```
function sendToParent() {
    $("table.list tr[class!=listViewThS1]:has(input:checked)").each(function () {
        $(window.opener.document).find('#description').val($(this).find('td:eq(2)').text());
    });        
}
```